Pivot dataframe values and its unit
I have the input dataframe in the following format:
id  city    state date      param  value unit
1   Phoenix AZ    4-21-2024 temp   100  F
2   Phoenix AZ    4-21-2024 prec   0    mm
3   Phoenix AZ    4-21-2024 wind   2    mph
4   Phoenix AZ    4-20-2024 temp   101  F
5   Phoenix AZ    4-20-2024 prec   0    NaN
6   Phoenix AZ    4-20-2024 wind   4    mph
7   Seattle WA    4-20-2024 temp   82   F
8   Seattle WA    4-20-2024 prec   3    mm
9   Seattle WA    4-20-2024 wind   5    mph

I want this data pivoted into this format:
id  city    state date       temp prec wind temp_unit prec_unit wind_unit
1   Phoenix AZ    4-21-2024  100  0    2    F         mm        mph
2   Phoenix AZ    4-20-2024  101  0    4    F                   mph
3   Seattle WA    4-20-2024  82   3    5    F         mm        mph

How do I pivot the dataframe on param and get the value and its corresponding unit?

You can just pass a list with multiple columns/values

I cannot do that because unit is nota numeric type

@Shanke you can use non-numeric data, I provided the example

You can pivot, flatten the MultiIndex, then reset_index:
out = df.pivot(index=['city', 'state', 'date'], columns='param', values=['value', 'unit'])

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' if x[0]!='value' else x[1])

out.reset_index(inplace=True)

Output:
      city state       date prec temp wind unit_prec unit_temp unit_wind
0  Phoenix    AZ  4-20-2024    0  101    4       NaN         F       mph
1  Phoenix    AZ  4-21-2024    0  100    2        mm         F       mph
2  Seattle    WA  4-20-2024    3   82    5        mm         F       mph

